# Converting a string to a date - Inaccurate result

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I have a string that looks like this: `2013-08-18` I need to convert this string into something that I can use to compare to another `Date` to see how many days have elapsed between the two. I came up with the following code to get it into a `Calendar` type, which is what my other variable is in. However, I'm getting inconsistent results that I don't understand. Here is my code:

```
String prefDate = prefs.getString("last_update", "2000-01-01");
System.err.println("oncreate prefDate: " + prefDate);

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
Date date = new Date();
date = df.parse(prefDate);
Calendar last_update = Calendar.getInstance();
last_update.setTime(date);

Date verify = new Date(last_update.getTimeInMillis());
System.err.println("verify: " + verify);
```

The output looks like this:

`oncreate prefDate: 2013-08-18`

`verify: Fri Jan 18 00:08:00 MST 2013`

I'm not particularly concerned about the difference in formatting between the two outputs. But what is clearly wrong is that the outcome of all of this is off by 8 months - a bit outside of my error tolerance. Can anyone see what I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `yyyy-mm-dd` to `yyyy-MM-dd` and refer Documentation of `SimpleDateFormat` for detailed information